# Assigning Matrix Values using For Statement - Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am working on HackerRank that is a platform that allows students to upload their Homeworks code, then the platform runs some random tests on our code. On this opportunity, my teacher has asked me to create a matrix on base from the input from HackerRank and then fill it also with more inputs from this platform.

I have created this code to create a matrix with the dimensions on which HackerRank wants and also refill it with the values generated of the platform but seems to have an error on my code and I don't see it.

It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:14)
```

My code:

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] array = new int [prompt.nextInt()+1][prompt.nextInt()];
    
    // Create matrix
    for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < array[a].length; b++){
           array[a][b] = prompt.nextInt();          /*This is the line 14*/
        }
    }
    
    for (int h=0; h < array.length; h++){ 
        for(int c=0; c < array[h].length; c++){ 
            System.out.printf("%5d",array[h][c]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a *Scanner* Throws a *NoSuchElementException* it means that you're trying to read from the scanner when you've already reached the end of the input.

Try using *hasNextInt* just before the *nextInt* in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` in this case indicates that there are no more tokens to be read. Did you provide enough values on the input?

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--